# Prevent UIDatePicker from defaulting to current year

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, date, datapicker

I have got a `UIDatePicker` to pick up Date of Birth. If someone doesn't select a year it defaults to current year. How can I prevent datepicker from defaulting to the current year? Please help.

Thanks

Sonia

Comment: Is there a way i can add an alert msg when default is not selected? I want user to select month and year, but if they only select month and pick a date from the calender it revets back to current year. I am now thinking when current year is defaulted to add an alert msg. Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It has to default to some year.  You could set a maximum date though (like 1 year ago), and then set the date of the `UIDatePicker` to an invalid date (like today).  Then just don't let the user continue if they haven't changed the year to a valid year.

Comment: Is there a way i can add an alert msg when default is not selected? I want user to select month and year, but if they only select month and pick a date from the calender it revets back to current year. I am now thinking when current year is defaulted to add an alert msg. Can you please help? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Before showing the date picker, you could call upon the

```
- (void)setDate:(NSDate *)date animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

method with the required date and the `UIDatePicker` will display that date when it comes on screen.

Answer (score 0):

According to [The UIDatePicker Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDatePicker_Class/Reference/UIDatePicker.html) You can simply change the Date Property's value and thus changing the default value - wich is the control's creation date

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your comment about a message - have you tried something like

```
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Please Enter correct birthday year" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
```

Alert views are pop-up views that appear over the current view on the iPhone.

You may find [iPhone Development 101 - UIAlertView](http://www.idev101.com/code/User_Interface/UIAlertView.html) informative